# matrix-vector multiplication with openMP on arm

Tags: c++, multithreading, arm, openmp

I am very disappointed with the performance of OpenMP ( especially on my arm device )

In the project i am planning i will need to do a lot of simple matrix-vec-multiplications ( affine transformations some may call it )

so i started some tests, to see what would be the fastest way to do this

the matrices i am talking about will have a dimension of about 1000x1000

at first i want to show my code, maybe you spot something obviously wrong with it

1) time measuring

```
auto start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t ttp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start_time);
std::cout << std::ctime(&ttp) << std::endl;
while((std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start_time) < std::chrono::seconds(time_span)) {
    const Vector& calc_vec = in_vecs[distr(eng)];
    const Matrix& calc_mat = in_mats[distr(eng)];
    calc_mat.mulVec(calc_vec, o);
    i++;
}
std::cout << "Performed : " << i << " Matrix-Vector multiplications in " << time_span << " sec's with naiv impl" << std::endl;
i=0;
start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
ttp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start_time);
std::cout << std::ctime(&ttp) << std::endl;
while((std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start_time) < std::chrono::seconds(time_span)) {
    const Vector& calc_vec = in_vecs[distr(eng)];
    const Matrix& calc_mat = in_mats[distr(eng)];
    calc_mat.mulVec(calc_vec, o, ParallelMode::OpenMP);
    i++;
}
std::cout << "Performed : " << i << " Matrix-Vector multiplications in " << time_span << " sec's with openmp impl" << std::endl;
```

i created 200 random input-matrices and input-vectors before, and in the loop i randomly choose one, to trash the cache ( i believe this will simulate real-life applications better ), **time_span** was set to 20secs

2) now the implementions of the mat-vec multiplications

```
static inline void NaivMultiplication
(const double* const * mat, const double* in, double* out, size_t inVecSize, size_t numRows) {
    for(size_t row=0; row < numRows; row++) {
    double sum=0;
    for(size_t col=0; col < inVecSize; col++) {
        sum += mat[row][col] * in[col];
    }
    out[row] = sum;
    }
}

static inline void openMPMultiplication
(const double* const * mat, const double* in, double* out, size_t inVecSize, size_t numRows) {
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for(size_t row=0; row < numRows; row++) {
    double sum=0;
    for(size_t col=0; col < inVecSize; col++) {
        sum += mat[row][col] * in[col];
    }
    out[row] = sum;
    }
}
```

the signature of these functions is rather odd, because i want do to the test with OpenCL later, i decided this heavy-pointer-like implementation

Ok, here are the results : 
on my i5-6600 with 4 cores, the program was able to perform

- 60.000 multiplications single-threaded
- 150.000 multiplications multi-threaded

so almost 2 cores are busy creating threads?

on my arm Exynos5422 Cortex™-A15 2Ghz with 4 cores running its even worse :

- 15.000 multiplications single-threaded
- **9.000** multiplications multi-threaded

---

- both tests were run on linux with gcc-5.3 (-O2 -fopenmp)
- with *top* i checked, that 4cores were actually at 100%
- Can anyone explain this to me?
- is it really so costly to create 4 threads per multiplication?

i mean, i have no data-dependencies, no synchronisation ( except the implicit 'join' at the end of each mult-operation

thx in advance, sry for my english ( non-native speaker ;) )

Comment: What about single thread performance measure, without `openmp`? Why you not use `mtune`, `-mfpu=neon`?

Comment: It's likely going to be easier to use existing high-performance linear-algebra libraries like [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net) or [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net) which implement the standard [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) api for linear algebra.  Both of those (and probably others) support multithreading for ARM.

Comment: -mtune and -mfpu had no effect, turning of -fopenmp had the expected effect ( same performance in both testcases ), for now i dont want do use i high level lib for this, as i want to understand how things work before i use libs ( wich are often optimized for the general case ). But i will benchmark blas tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

For large enough matrix, `mat-vec-mul` is a memory bandwidth bounded operation instead of a cpu bounded operation, which means your speed is limited by reading/writing matrix data from/to RAM. In this case you won't get expected speed-up by using multi-threads.

[The 3rd figure of this link](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark) shows when the matrix is large enough (larger than cache), the performance drops a lot for `mat-vec-mul`.

As the cache size and RAM bandwidth often much lower on ARM than desktop CPUs, you could get more penalties on multi-threading.

On the other hand, it is usually a very bad practice to implement basic matrix/vector operations by your own when you don't know the tricks/theories inside. The good way is to use existing high performance BLAS libraries such as OpenBLAS, MKL, cuBLAS, Eigen ...

Since you are using modern C++ on ARM, I would suggest you use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). It has much more friendly API compared to OpenBLAS, which also has ARM-optimized code path. And you could control the multi-threading to compare the performance with Eigen very easily. All you need to do is something like:

```
int len = 1000;
Eigen::MatrixXf mat = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(len,len);
Eigen::VectorXf in = Eigen::VectorXf::Random(len);
Eigen::VectorXf out(len);

int num_threads = 4;
Eigen::setNbThreads(num_threads);

out = mat * in;
```

Comment: When using openmp on an ht or numa platform you will need the openmp affinity settings unless using a library like mkl which may set them.